# A weird definition of regular function

Tags: analysis, derivatives, definition, smooth-functions

Consider the following definition, where immersions are defined:

[image]

Later the author states:

[image]

**The problem:** In the definition, a regular function is defined to have constant rank in particular. But later it is stated, as if it were something that would need a proof, that the rank of an immersion (which in particular is a regular function), is constant in a neighborhood. This doesn't make sense.
What am I missing here? Maybe the author messed up the definition of "regular function" and assumed too much?

Later the author states "Let $\varphi$ be regular at $0$, i.e. $D\varphi (0)$ is injective. How can I make sense of this, if regularity was defined as a property holding for the whole domain, not just a single point? (Also, $D\varphi (0)$ being injective is something that pertains to an immersion, not a regular function, according to the definitions above.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlined part in second picture actually has nothing to do with the first picture. That is simply an application of the property of continuous functions.

**Update**

If not defined, then you may understand the regularity as

> $f \colon U \to \mathbb R^n$ where $U \subseteq \mathbb R^k$ is **regular** at $x_0 \in U$ if $\mathrm Df(x_0)$ has full rank, i.e. $$\mathrm {rk}(\mathrm Df(x_0)) = \min \{n, k\}.$$

When the author says

> i.e. $\mathrm Df(0)$ is injective

there should be some statements before about the dimensions of domain and codomain, otherwise this is not fully supported.

Comment: But then it's nonsensical to formulate this remark by stating it as a property for immersions, right? (See please also my edit of the question.)

Comment: @temo I just mean the reasoning of this sentence have not use these concepts.

Comment: So you agree it doesn't make sense to state that remark?

Comment: @temo No. I do not know why the author give this remark, since I have not read this note. Maybe this is a review of multivariate calculus [if you are reading manifolds, i assume] or this would be useful for future reference.

Comment: If the definition of regularity at one point has not given before, then this might be a flaw of organizations of materials.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing that out +1. Could you please also answer what I wrote under "Later the author states", so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: The author assumes $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. But the requirement of $D\varphi (0)$ being injective actually is *more* than just requiring regularity (in your sense) at that point, since it actually means being an immersion at that point, right? So the author is wrong to conflate regularity at that point with D\varphi (0)$ being injective, right? Also, could you please tell me why are immersions and submersion global concepts? I could just as well formulate them for point, as for the whole domain?

Comment: @temo Did s/he say anything like $k \leqslant n$? If not then the statement is not rigorous, and you may say the author made mistakes.

Comment: You are right, the author says $k\leqslant n$. But I'm not sure how that helps...

Comment: @temo If that is the case, the 2nd paragraph in the first picture would apply, specifically the first sentence. That is a basic result from linear algebra.

Comment: So you agree that it would have been better if the author would have said "Let $\varphi$ be an immersion at $0$ instead of "Let $\varphi$ be regular at $0$, i.e. $D\varphi (0)$ is injective" ?

Comment: @temo I think they are both acceptable if $k \leqslant n$ was stated before.